# Pausing Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, timer, wait, thread-sleep

Hy!
So I'm starting with netbeans java gui development and I have run into this problem:

I have made a window with a button and a text field. When the user clicks the button I want the text field to start typing itself with a delay. So for example:

```
textfield.text=h
wait(1) sec
textfield.text=he
wait(1) sec
textfield.text=hel
wait(1) sec
textfield.text=hell
wait(1) sec
textfield.text=hello
```

I have already tried with `Thread.sleep()`, but in the example above it waits 4 seconds or so and after that displays the whole text (so it's not giving me the typo effect that I would want).

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Check out this answer that implements a Swing timer specifically made to do what you're wanting it to do.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13198256/2142219

Answer (score 5):

If you use `Thread.sleep(...)` or any other code that delays the Swing event thread, you'll end up putting the entire Swing event thread to sleep, and with it your application. The key here is to instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). In the Timer's ActionListener's actionPerformed method, add a letter and increment your index, and then use that index to decide what letter to next add.

i.e.,

```
String helloString = "hello";

// in the Timer's ActionListener's actionPerformed method:
if (index >= helloString.length()) {
  // stop the Timer here
} else {
  String currentText = textField.getText();
  currentText += helloString.charAt(index);
  textField.setText(currentText);
  index++;
}
```

Comment: May you write a full example of a code which would suit my example? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @user2580136: no, trust me, you will gain ***much*** more and learn much more by using my ideas and writing your full example code yourself. Then if you get stuck, please come on back with your code and your question. I've left you a link to the [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), so please give that a look as well. Good luck!

Comment: I shall try, but I'm afraid that I'm gonna end up in a lot of tears :/

Comment: @user2580136: it's all part of the learning experience. Better to learn to sweat for code then to beg for code.

Comment: @user2580136: nah, keep trying and you'll get it!

Comment: @user2580136: here is some sample code that I've created as part of an answer to a different question: [Swing Timer Code Exampe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6488068/522444).

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using something like this:

```
Timer a,b,c

Timer c=new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){textfield.setText(abc)}})

Timer b=new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){textfield.setText(ab);c.start()}})

Timer a=new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){textfield.setText(a);b.start()}})

a.setRepeats(false);
b.setRepeats(false);
c.setRepeats(false);

a.start()
```

Does anybody know a more simple method with the same effect maybe?